# why is static inner class singleton thread safe

Tags: java

As the title said, why is static nested class singleton thread-safe?

```
public class Singleton {
    private static class SingletonHolder {
        public static Singleton instance;

        public static Singleton getInstance() {
            if (null == instance) {
                instance = new Singleton();
            }
        }
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return SingletonHolder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, your code can't be compiled.

Comment: Firstly what you are trying to achieve is not going to be singleton as you can still make 'n' number of objects of this class.

Comment: The reason for this mentioned class is not a Singleton and can able to create more than one instance is maybe checking wrong null checking. ```if (null == instance)``` need to be changed with ```if(instance == null)``` instead. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The code you show is not technically thread-safe. This sort of dodgy code often gets mangles.

The code should look like:

```
public class Singleton  {    
    private static class SingletonHolder {    
        public static final Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    }    

    public static Singleton getInstance() {    
        return SingletonHolder.instance;    
    }    
}
```

Here we are assigning within a static initialiser (of `SingletonHolder`), which will be seen by any thread accessing it with correct *happens-before* relationship. There's nothing really special about the nested class, it just allows the outer class to be used without immediately constructing the singleton object. Almost certainly this is entirely **pointless**, but it seems to please some people.

As ever [**mutable**] singletons are a **really bad** idea.

Comment: Your code won't compile. SingletonHolder has no `getInstance()` method

Comment: what's the point of immutable singleton?

Comment: @zhong.j.yu Well it wouldn't be a Singleton by any reasonable definition. Single instance implementations are useful for functors (such as `Comparator`s) and distinguished value.

Comment: there's no distinction between one functor or a dozen; a singleton functor is only a performance optimization, it has no significance to application logic.

Comment: The code does compile, comments above appear to have been edited into the answer.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline you can add a private Singleton constructor `private Singleton() {}` to make this example complete.

Comment: @RamanSahasi The code is supposed to have minimal changes from the original. Hiding the constructor and making the class final would be unnecessary distractions.

Comment: I would disagree with your answer as i can still make "new Singleton()"

Comment: @Prashant As my comment immediately above yours: Together with any useful methods, the private constructor was elided from the original question and, therefore to keep the differences relevant to the point in hand, also in my answer.

Answer (score 9):

It's thread-safe because the JVM handles lazily loading the nested class.

However, the code you posted doesn't seem to be using this pattern correctly (you shouldn't have a null check), and I think that actually breaks the thread safety. Here's a nice article where you can read more about why this pattern works and how to use it correctly:

[Initialization-on-demand holder idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_on_demand_holder_idiom#Example_Java_Implementation)

Comment: The op's code is definitely unsafe...

Comment: OP ninja-edited the question.  The original was as in Tom Hawtin's answer