# convert mutable variable to immutable in java with less pain

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, immutability, mutable

sometime i have no choice to use `mutable` variable instead of `immutable` variables i know how many ways can create immutable vars but i wonder this way also correct its really convert `mutable` to `immutable` and i dont use `concurrency` or `multithreading` in my code just Curious?

```
public class Config implements FindIt {
....
    private final class DateHolder{

    private final Date dateContainDateObject;

    DateHolder(String date) throws ParseException {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
        dateContainDateObject = dateFormat.parse(date);
    }

    public Date getDate(){
        return dateContainDateObject;
    }

   }
}
```

this is nested class and i use it like

```
private DateHolder holder;
```

and fill the `holder` variable in `Config` constructor class so `holder` variable are `ThreadSafe` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date is a mutable object. Making it final means you can't change the reference to it, but you can still change what's at the reference (java.util.Date/Calendar nastiness strikes again, switch to the Java 8/Joda Time way if you can).

Don't expose any references to the Date member to the outside world. Instead make a defensive copy and pass that back instead. You might consider saving the time value as a final long instance member and only instantiating a Date when you need it.

Comment: Or -- really, honestly, a much better option -- don't use `java.util.Date`.

Comment: ...and use the new and improved APIs in the `java.time` package where everything is immutable and thread-safe.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov tank you but i don't want target the last JDK i like support more JDk version

Comment: Then use a third-party library like Joda Time.  I'd really rather lose a finger than use `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 1):

can say is safe when you make class private and non-static, when you  create form Config class you have only one DateHolder .

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29

[why is static inner class singleton thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17799976/why-is-static-inner-class-singleton-thread-safe)

http://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-create-immutable-class