# Not getting expected result when updating AtomicInteger variable in multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, atomicinteger

In this code I'm using 10 threads updating an AtomicInteger variable. I expect the final result of **Counter.getInstance().holder.n** to be 1000000, but it prints out random number like 991591.
What's wrong with my code?

```
public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Thread> list = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            list.add(new Thread() {

                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                        Counter.getInstance().holder.n.incrementAndGet();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        for (Thread thread : list) {
            thread.start();
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(Counter.getInstance().holder.n);


    } 
} 

class Counter {
    private static Counter counter;
    Holder holder = new Holder();


    public static Counter getInstance() {
        if (counter == null) {
            counter = new Counter();
        }
        return counter;
    }
    class Holder {
        AtomicInteger n = new AtomicInteger(0);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your Counter singleton is not thread-safe, and sleeping 10 seconds doesn't guarantee that all threads have finished running. Use a simple static variable for your atomic integer, and call thread.join() on all the threads (in an additional loop) to wait for their termination.

Comment: Can you explain why the Singleton is not thread-safe? and how to make it thread-safe?

Comment: Because two threads can concurrently call getInstance(), both see that counter is null, and both create a new Counter. And since there is no synchronization whatsoever, even if one thread has already set the static counter to a non-null value, the other thread has no guarantee to see it. To make it thread-safe: just use `static final AtomicInteger N = new AtomicInteger(0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two major concurrent issues here:

1. You don't wait for every `Thread` to finish work correctly. There are multiple ways to achieve that, the simplest is to use `Thread.join()`.
2. Your singleton implementation doesn't seem correct. I suppose you intended to implement it with an inner class. It seems that this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17800038/5558122) can help to understand what's happening here.

Here is the implementation that seems more or less correct.

```java
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        List<Thread> list = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            list.add(new Thread() {

                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                        Counter.getInstance().n.incrementAndGet();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        for (Thread thread : list) {
            thread.start();
        }

        for (Thread thread : list) {
            thread.join();
        }

        System.out.println(Counter.getInstance().n);
    }
}

class Counter {
    public AtomicInteger n = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public static Counter getInstance() {
        return Holder.instance;
    }
    private static class Holder {
        private static final Counter instance = new Counter();
    }
}
```

You can use something like `CountDownLatch` as well. For example:

```java
final int count = 10;
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(count);
List<Thread> list = new ArrayList<Thread>();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    list.add(new Thread() {

        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                Counter.getInstance().n.incrementAndGet();
            }
            latch.countDown();
        }
    });
}
for (Thread thread : list) {
    thread.start();
}

latch.await();

System.out.println(Counter.getInstance().n);
```